# multiple UPDATE function, php sql, only updates last function

Tags: php, sql

i have an issue with my update function on php, i have the code to make the function work how ever it only ever updates the last function.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$stock_1 = $_POST['stock_1'];
$stock_2 = $_POST['stock_2'];
$stock_3 = $_POST['stock_3'];
$stock_4 = $_POST['stock_4'];
$stock_5 = $_POST['stock_5'];
$stock_6 = $_POST['stock_6'];

$sql = "UPDATE products ".
       "SET instock = $stock_1 ".
       "WHERE productid = 1" ;

$sql = "UPDATE products ".
       "SET instock = $stock_2 ".
       "WHERE productid = 2" ;
$sql = "UPDATE products ".
       "SET instock = $stock_3 ".
       "WHERE productid = 3" ;

$sql = "UPDATE products ".
       "SET instock = $stock_4 ".
       "WHERE productid = 4" ;

$sql = "UPDATE products ".
       "SET instock = $stock_5 ".
       "WHERE productid = 5" ;

$sql = "UPDATE products ".
       "SET instock = $stock_6 ".
       "WHERE productid = 6" ;


mysql_select_db('db_k0903037');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">3.5" Seagate SATA 2TB</td>
<td><input name="stock_1" type="text" id="stock_1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Samsung 2.5" SATA Hard Drive</td>
<td><input name="stock_2" type="text" id="stock_2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">8gb Kingston DDR3 RAM 1333mhz</td>
<td><input name="stock_3" type="text" id="stock_3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Apple MacBook Ram 8GB</td>
<td><input name="stock_4" type="text" id="stock_4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3</td>
<td><input name="stock_5" type="text" id="stock_5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Asus P8Z77-V PRO </td>
<td><input name="stock_6" type="text" id="stock_6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

thats my code and im struggling to see why it doesnt update all of them? obviously i put in the correct username and password!

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You put some water in glass, then you replace water with milk in that glass, then you again replace milk with wine and then drink it, what will you end up drinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do that in a loop?

```
for($i=1;$i<=6;++$i){
  ${'stock_'.$i} = $_POST['stock_'.$i];
  $sql = "UPDATE products SET instock = ".${'stock_'.$i}." WHERE productid = ".$i ;
  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
  // ...
}
```

or just

```
for($i=1;$i<=6;++$i){
  $var = $_POST['stock_'.$i];
  $sql = "UPDATE products SET instock = ".$var." WHERE productid = ".$i ;
  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
  // ...
}
```

Comment: this works great! thought about a loop but didnt quite know how, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `mysql_select_db('db_k0903037');` must go at the top of the code, and then you have to do

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

after each `$sql = "...";`.

The way you do it, is you set the `$sql` string to something different each time, but you don't actually execute that query. `mysql_query` does the actual executing :)